# Sidebar Menu Bootstrap Column li not taking width of parent container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

RE-EDIT Of Question

In the code below I have the desired layout I want except for one thing. 
I have the li tag highlighted aqua. I did this so I could monitor it while I would edit the css in codepen until I got what I wanted. Still haven't figured it out. I want the hightlighted li tag to take up 100% of the width of the container it's in. I want them to be stacked right on top of each other so it looks clean when hovering over them like you see in most dashboards. The padding around columns came from gutters built in to the bootstrap grid system. I assigned the `no-gutters` class to it thinking that would help me. Still a no go. Is container-fluid the only thing left that could be causing `li` tag nested in `aside` from being able to go 100% in the width because of padding?

```css
.side-menu {

    background:#0C1E1D;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top:1%;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;

}

.profile-pic {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: auto;
}

.btn {
    background:#424242;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition:
}

.list {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.list li {
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    transition: 1s;
    overflow: auto;
    background:aqua;

}

.list li:hover {

    cursor: pointer;

}

.content {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">  
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <aside class="side-menu col-md-2  text-center">
            <img src="https://cdn.bandmix.com/bandmix_us/media/1049/1049150/1119049-p.jpg" class="img-circle img-responsive profile-pic"   alt="profile-pic "/>
            <h4 class="text-center">Steven Sanders</h4>
            <button class="btn btn-large text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Message</button>
            <ul class="list list-unstyled">
                <li>Test</li>
                <li>Test</li>
                <li>Test</li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <main class="col-md-10 content">
            <h1 class="text-center">Dashboard</h1>      
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks fine on a medium and large screen which you specified the layout for.

Comment: The code is kind of a mess. `container-fluid row` shouldn't be used together, nor should `container` and `col-2`. Read about [the Bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/).